# Error MSB3073 in postbuild event VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

In the process build of a huge enterprise C# VS2013 **sometimes** I get the **error MSB3073 after the in the post build event**. Unfortunately all the answers on this topic did not tackle exactly this problem.
The error message is the following:
*C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4548,5): error MSB3073: The command "@call "D:\TFS\SUV\Dev\2.2.28\DotNet\GUI\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.Post-Build.cmd" D:\TFS\SUV\Dev\2.2.28\DotNet\GUI\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV\ " exited with code 1073750991.*

I was not able to find a criterion to reproduce it sistematically, I only figured out it never happens if I run Clean before Rebuild.  Setting verbosity of the MSBuild log to diagnostics did not give me any clue.
The last statement of the cmd file executed in the post build is "SUCCESS", which appears in the log.

- Here is the log of a failed build

  ERRORLEVEL = 0 (TaskId:2172)
  SUCCESS ! (TaskId:2172)  **==> end of Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.Post-Build.cmd file**
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4548,5): error MSB3073: The command "@call "D:\TFS\SUV\Dev\2.2.28\DotNet\GUI\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.Post-Build.cmd" D:\TFS\SUV\Dev\2.2.28\DotNet\GUI\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV\ " exited with code 1073750991.
  Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:2172)
- Here is the log of a successful build:

ERRORLEVEL = 0 (TaskId:2172)
SUCCESS ! (TaskId:2172) ***==> end of Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.Post-Build.cmd file***
Done executing task "Exec". (TaskId:2172)
Done building target "PostBuildEvent" in project "Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.csproj".: (TargetId:3611)
Target "CoreBuild: (TargetId:3612)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\TFS\SUV\Dev\2.2.28\DotNet\GUI\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.csproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.csproj".: (TargetId:3612)

The error number 1073750991 looks more as a memory pointer that to a coded value.  Does the couple of numbers Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4548,5) have a meaning ?
Sorry for the long description, I will be very grateful for any hint.

The cmd file in question basically does this:
nmake.exe %PROJECTDIR%\Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.Post-Build.mak
echo ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%

and Allianz.Vita.Web.SUV.Post-Build.mak basically is a sequence of xcopy statements as
@xcopy /R /Y .....\FRAMEWORK\Deploy\Allianz.Framework.Security.dll.config .\Bin\
None of them reports (apparently) an error.

Comment: **(4548,5)** is the row and column numbers of the **Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets** file where error was ocured (the call to **Exec** command)

Comment: Why do you need PostBuildEvent with nmake inside which call another file to just copy several files? You have another option with msbuild - [Copy task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx)

Comment: @stukselbax Thanks for the hint, I'll try the Copy task; it seems a problem of simultaneous access to a file. Monday I'll give again a look to the Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets file, I remember it had less lines.